# How to authenticate Quart websockets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio, quart

From a medium article by the creator of `Quart`: https://medium.com/@pgjones/websockets-in-quart-f2067788d1ee :

> **Authentication**
>
> The ability to control the acceptance is most useful when authorising
>   requests, as it allows the request headers to be checked and either
>   the upgrade accepted or a 401 returned. A simple example is,
>
> ```
> def auth_required(func):
>     @wraps(func)
>     async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
>         auth = websocket.authorization      
>         if (
>             auth is not None and
>             auth.username == current.app.config['USERNAME'] and
>             compare_digest(
>                 auth.password, current.app.config['PASSWORD'],
>             )
>         ):
>             return await func(*args, **kwargs)
>         else:
>             abort(401)
>     return wrapper
>
> @app.websocket('/ws')
> @auth_required
> async def ws():
>     ...
> ```

But how does client-side javascript cause the `websocket.authorization` attribute to be populated?

`var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + 'user' + ':' + 'pass' + '@' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/ws');` appears to have been deprecated in the last couple of years, and custom headers in the HTTP request for a websocket are not supported.

Comment: Have you ruled out using a cookie?

Comment: Yep I see how to retrieve the cookie now using websockets. But am I correct in thinking the `quart.flask_patch` with `flask_login` can't be used with websockets in Quart? So one way or another I have to roll my own system basically?  Set a challenge with expiry etc and keep some state server side?

Comment: Yea `flask_login` has no concept of websockets so it does nothing on websocket requests.